# prevent page reload of the browser on navigating to another page - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to prevent page reload with angularjs. presently with the code I have, the page does not reload but it never navigates to another page. here is the code

```
 $scope.login = function(){
        $scope.loading="loading";
        Service.authenticate($.param({
            username : $scope.username,
            password : $scope.password,
        }), function(res) {
            if(res !== undefined){
                if(res.success){


                    var windowElem = angular.element($window);
                      windowElem.on('beforeunload', function (event) {

                      event.preventDefault();
                      $(location).attr('href', '/dashboard');
                      })

                }else{

                    $scope.error = res.message;

                }
            }
```

I don't know if I am trying to re-invent the wheel but the page is not navigating without reloading

Comment: Are you using state router in your app ?

Comment: no. it is not an spa. I just want to disable page refresh/reload on the browser but still navigates to url

Comment: mr. downvoter, please sir what am I doing wrong. Not just downvoting, at least show me my wrong so that I can learn and improve

Answer (score 0):

my advise is to use uirouter ( https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki ).

Register the module in you app

angular
    .module('myApp', [
        ...
        'ui.router',
        ...
    ])

Configure the $stateProvider inside you config function

.config( function ( $stateProvider, ... ) {

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('main.login', {
            url : "/",
            views : {
                "login" : {
                    controller : 'LoginCtrl',
                    templateUrl : 'views/login/login.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

...

After a successful login you can use the $state service to change the 
state ( so the page ) of your app, obviously without page reload.

$state.go('main.whereverRegisteredState', {some: data});

I will not explain to you about application setup, controller, view or service injection, just follow official documentation.

Hope it helps